# What is the domain of $y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the differential equation $y'=\frac{3x^2}{3y^2-4}$. We want to find the domain of $y$. From the equation we have that $y^{3}-4y=x^{3}+C$, for $C\in \mathbb{R}$. From this relation, how can we find the domain of $y$ ?

Comment: Obviously, you have $y\colon E\to\mathbb{P}^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $y'=\frac{3x^2}{3y^2-4}$ we can see denominator of the fraction can't be zero so $3y^2-4\neq0$  hence $y\neq\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$.

So the domain of $y$ is $\mathbb{R}-\{\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$}

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome !